# How to retrieve empty set from cassandra using SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-cassandra

When I am trying to retrieve data from Cassandra using SpringBoot framework, one of the field in the POJO class is Set and the empty [] column always returns null instead of empty Set.

I tried using @CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.SET). However, It did not help and I still receive Empty Set as null from Cassandra.

I tried using @CassandraType(type = DataType.Name.SET). However, It did not help and I still receive Empty Set as null from Cassandra.

"blacklist":null

Expected output should be like below
"blacklist":[]

Actual output is like below
"blacklist":null

blacklist is a Set in pojo and Set column in Cassandra database.

Answer (score 0):

With Hibernate OGM 5.x. @PostLoad annotation support is available now. This method annotated with this annotation will get called after fetching from database.
Solution (add below method to your POJO):
@PostLoad
public void postLoad() {if(blacklist == null) blacklist = new HashSet<>();}

Apologies for formatting issues as i am on mobile right now.

Reference: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.0/hem/en-US/html/listeners.html

Comment: Hi, do you think I need to check for null since it should be empty already coming from Cassandra. I think using this it can be done.

Comment: Cassandra is more or less a columnar database, so its null is not a null as in SQL. In Cassandra's null means that this column in this row does not exist at all in database and does not occupy any space.